# Specify .msi file location when using cx_Freeze?

Tags: python, windows-installer, cx-freeze

Using [`cx_Freeze`](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to build a `.msi` installer for a python GUI, how can I specify the location to save the newly built `.msi` file?

I do *not* want the file saved to the default `dist` folder, but instead I want to specify my own location for the file when it is created. I also want to use a `setup.py` file, *not* the command line. How can I do this?

I'm looking for the equivalent of the [`--target-dir`](https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/script.html#cmdoption-target-dir) option, but specified in the `setup.py`, instead of as a command line flag?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `target_name` to your `bdist_msi` options in `setup()`. This will create the MSI.

Or you can add `bdist_msi` the same way, as shown [here](https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/779#issuecomment-1555955654), which will put it in that folder with the default naming convention.

```
bdist_msi_options = {'target_name': 'path/to/your.msi'}
setup(
    name='name',
    ...
    options = {
        'build_exe': build_exe_options,
        'bdist_msi': bdist_msi_options,
    }
)
```